# Can a short rope used with Rope Trick create a “safe space” during combat?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, tactics

Rope trick in 5e says:

> You touch a length of rope that is **up to** 60 feet long. One end of the rope then rises into the air until the whole rope hangs perpendicular to the ground. At the upper end of the rope, an invisible entrance opens to an extradimensional space that lasts until the spell ends.
>
> The extradimensional space can be reached by climbing to the top of the rope.

Movement is halved when climbing. Theoretically a character with movement of 30 feet could climb down and up a 7 foot rope during a turn by expending 28 feet of movement (7ft × 2 each way)

Given these details, if a character casts Rope Trick with a 7 foot rope and climbs into the space... then on subsequent rounds could the character expend 14 feet of movement to climb down the rope, perform an action, then expend 14 feet of movement to climb up the rope and back into the extra-dimensional space?

Taking this further... could the rope be just 3 feet in height and a wizard duck into and out of the extradimensional space each round?

Of course, the risk at this low height is that enemies might climb into the space as well. A dragon could put its head through the hole and breathe. Other mayhem is possible. But, it may also give a character in dire condition a brief respite against ranged attacks or spells.

Comment: At first thought, it's a variant of this question: [How do I deal with players persistently arguing for rules loopholes, even after I've tried to finalise my rulings?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/110092/) Basically, using downsides of turns mechanics to get unfair advantage in combat.

Answer (score 36):

## The rules allow this, but...

There's nothing in the rules that prevents this from happening. However, there are a few things to consider about this tactic before employing it.

#### It can be immersion-breaking

Although it is technically within the rules of DnD to abuse the turn-based combat system for janky things like this, for some players this can break the sense of immersion that comes with good DnD. It can transform the fight from an epic tale about spell-slinging wizards to a videogame where you abuse the mechanics for maximum power. This kind of tactic is legal in the game, but does not make for a good story or in-universe character.

#### Any good DM can (and should) respond appropriately to shenanigans like this

For example, were I the DM here's how it'd play out. The first time you use Rope Trick as a sanctuary, some enemies might try to follow you up but it would mostly work out - this is what the spell is for, and it's a fun part of the game.

However, once you try the "climbing up and down" shenanigans, I'd just have enemies start readying actions. If they ready an attack, they can just attack you while you're on the rope. You could also have enemies stand at the bottom of the rope and attack your allies, and use attacks of opportunity whenever you attempt to climb back up. I also think it would be very reasonable to grant them advantage while attacking a climbing target. At this point, climbing up and down each turn is actually helping your enemies.

At the end of the day, there are a whole host of ways that climbing in and out is a poor tactical decision. That tactic leaves you spending a lot of time climbing up and down a rope, which is a poor use of movement and limits your positioning to a single location. While climbing you are fully exposed and can't use hands, but your enemies are free to reposition at will during their turns. Any slightly-intelligent enemy could use this highly advantageous situation to make your life miserable in a variety of ways.

#### You're missing the best use of Rope Trick

Rope trick is a fantastic spell for the use case you mentioned in the question:

> [to] give a character in dire condition a brief respite against ranged attacks or spells.

However, it works better *thematically* and *mechanically* to stay in the sanctuary. You can take a few turns to use healing potions and spells, regroup, and reconsider tactics. You could even have your whole party take a short rest. Popping in and out every turn can be immersion-breaking and actually hurt more than it helps mechanically.

Comment: This is a very good answer. The only thing I would add is "enemies would burn the rope to force you out"

Comment: In my group we have a rule that the NPCs can do whatever the PCs can. If a player abused this at my table then all their enemies would use this trick next time. This has kept our group relatively exploit free for many years.

Comment: @JPChapleau Very true. They could also toss any kind of persistent threat (hunting trap, fire spell, caltrops, etc) at the bottom, climb partway up the rope and hang out with readied actions, climb up after the players, tie some knives onto the rope, or even make their own rope trick. There's a whole wide range of ways a good DM could deal with this tactic.

Comment: @JPChapleau Burning the rope to “force someone out” could be challenging given that rope trick says, “...The rope can be pulled into the space, making the rope disappear from view outside the space...” This could be particularly quick given the OPs description that the rope is only 3-7 feet long. Additionally, even if the rope is burned, there is no description in the spell stating that would force characters out of the extradimensional space. Theoretically, they could jump out of the space down that 3-7 feet to the ground at will.

Comment: I would (while admitting this is an old answer) advise you change 'punish the tactic' to more like 'allow enemies to adapt to the tactic'. It's more nuanced, and one more step removed from the notion of punishing *players*

Answer (score 3):

Though your idea sounds interesting and is plausible by the rules, tactically, I would highly suggest against it, as it causes more problems than it solves.

## You're creating a beacon to attract enemies.

The wording of the spell states that, though you are invisible to everyone outside of the extra-dimensional space, the only way to truly hide would be to pull the rope into the space with you. However, revising the PHB, both pulling the rope up and dropping it would fall under *"Using an Object"* and would cost you an action each. Even if the DM is nice and considers it a bonus action, you'll still be unable to do both within one move.

That would mean that you'll be leaving behind a 7-foot tall pointer leading straight to you while alerting your enemies that you're a high-priority target. This will surely result in attracting many melee enemies to the base of your rope as it will create a focal point for ranged attackers.

*Note: This problem is also seen when players try to use illusionary spells like Mordenkainen's Private Sanctum to avoid being targeted, but then jump in and out of it all the time... the enemy still knows where you are.*

## Enemies can strategize too.

Having the rope exposed might not seem detrimental, but remember that your enemies have a certain level of intelligence, and won't take long before choosing to encumber you. This opens up three Opportunity Attacks that your character will face:

1. Ready is an action available to enemies as well as PCs, meaning you can face up to 24 melee attackers waiting for you to climb down (8 opponents with regular weapons and 16 with reach weapons) If each opponent chooses to use Ready, then the minute your feet hit the floor, you got a massacre of priority attacks coming your way.
2. Ranged Ready. The same as before, but with ranged attacks, they can choose to hit you when you're fully outside of the space, but still at the top of the rope. Failing a saving throw here would both cause falling damage and most likely prone as you need to refocus to get up.
3. Even without ranged attacks, an enemy with enough reach can cut the rope short. Since the spell says nothing about the spell being broken if the rope is cut, all they would have to do is set a trap for when you fall, cut the rope and wait up to an hour. You'll either try to get out or the spell will cancel and you'll fall right into a pit of swords, a bear trap, or anything else they can come up with. Meanwhile, the bulk of the enemy can focus on wiping out your party, either slaughtering them or causing them to think you a coward for your cunning plan.
4. All it takes are two melee fighters at the base of your rope and climbing would also cause Opportunity Attacks every time you leave.

All in all, to cast one spell will cost you many prioritized hits.

## You cannot use the space as half-cover

Reading the RAW, the way to leave the extra-dimensional space is to *climb* down. This means that unless you have enough room to utilize the rope, you'll be stuck in there for an hour. I could be wrong, but since climb is the key word there, it defeats the purpose of the sanctum if you don't use the rope as a failsafe passage. Though, if you found a way to creatively word your entering and exiting as climbing, you're still faced with being a priority.

All in all, the one key problem I can see in your plan is in how enemies prioritize their targets:

> Swords are troublesome. Flying things are more troublesome. Tricky things are most troublesome. Must work on tricky enemy first.

Comment: Don't forget that you get one free object interaction per turn. So handling the rope won't necessarily cost an action.

Comment: If I remember correctly, there's a difference between interaction and action. If everything was prone to a free ability, feats such as Crossbow Expert would be useless as loading a crossbow would be no problem. In this case, I can agree that grabbing the rope can be considered a free interaction, but pulling 7 feet of rope up would involve multiple actions (grabbing the rope, bracing yourself and pulling it up) as well as a lot of time for one turn. Could be wrong, but I think the calculation still stands.

Comment: the DM is always allowed to determine that something takes more than a free object interaction in the rules, but I think it might be a bit too prescriptive. Not everything is allowed to be done as a free object interaction though crossbows specifically do not take any kind of action to reload and specify exactly how they need to be done therefore a free object interaction would not apply there.

Comment: For example dropping a rope would easily be a free object interaction at my table. Pulling up the rope would, at most, be 1 action. I would recommend explicitly saying that the rules do not say and that it is up to the DM.

Comment: There's a lot more that can be considered (concentration needed to aim a spell, weight of the rope, how hard it's swaying when you drop it) that can all create adverse effects, however I still stand that, given a round should account to 6 seconds in the world (PHB, P.189) the math still doesn't add up to drop a rope, climb down, aim, fire, climb back up and pull the rope up within that short of time.

Comment: @VictorB sure, but I think you can still say that and accurately represent the rules. Right now you imply the rules say concretely that these things take at least an action. In reality, you think it is reasonable that this is the case, and the rules say no such thing. My recommendation is to make that distinction clearer. You can still make your point and be accurate to the rules.

Comment: @Rubiksmoose I've searched through the PHB a few times now regarding this and the only ruling that applies is "Using an Object" on P.193, and a passage about climbing on slippery surfaces, leaving the wording in the former section to be considered. Though I did say that pulling and dropping the rope should be considered separate actions, my actual statement is that they would at least be considered a bonus action (since the book states bonus actions need to be clearly indicated or else fall into action category.) I am not implying awarding each more than one action point.